# loadinBackground error in parse

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uicollectionview

I have problems with loadinbackground. I am getting an error saying Cannot Invoke loadinBackground with no arguments.

The following is my code, I have looked in the internet and don't know why this is not working.

```
 import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // Container to store the view table selected object
    var currentObject : PFObject?

    // Some text fields
    @IBOutlet weak var topsLabel: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var topsImageView: PFImageView!

    var updateObject : PFObject?

    // The save button
    @IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {

        // Use the sent country object or create a new country PFObject
        if let updateObjectTest = currentObject as PFObject? {
            updateObject = currentObject! as PFObject
        } else {
            updateObject = PFObject(className:"Tops")
        }

        // Update the object
        if let updateObject = updateObject {

            updateObject["topsLabel"] = topsLabel.text

            // Create a string of text that is used by search capabilites
            var searchText = (topsLabel.text).lowercaseString
            updateObject["searchText"] = searchText

            // Update the record ACL such that the new record is only visible to the current user
            updateObject.ACL = PFACL(user: PFUser.currentUser()!)

            // Save the data back to the server in a background task
            updateObject.save()
        }

        // Return to table view
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Unwrap the current object object
        if let object = currentObject {
            if let value = object["topsLabel"] as? String {
                topsLabel.text = value


            // Display standard question image
            var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
            topsImageView.image = initialThumbnail

            // Replace question image if an image exists on the parse platform
            if let thumbnail = object["topsImageView"] as? PFFile {
                topsImageView.file = thumbnail
                topsImageView.loadInBackground()
            }
        }
    }
}


    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destinationViewController.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
```

Tops View

```
import UIKit
import Parse

var tops = [PFObject]()

class TopsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {

    // Connection to the search bar
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    // Connection to the collection view
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Wire up search bar delegate so that we can react to button selections
        searchBar.delegate = self

        // Resize size of collection view items in grid so that we achieve 3 boxes across
        let cellWidth = ((UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width) - 32 - 30 ) / 3
        let cellLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        cellLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: cellWidth, height: cellWidth)
    }

    /*
    ==========================================================================================
    Ensure data within the collection view is updated when ever it is displayed
    ==========================================================================================
    */

    // Load data into the collectionView when the view appears
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        loadCollectionViewData()
    }

    /*
    ==========================================================================================
    Fetch data from the Parse platform
    ==========================================================================================
    */

    func loadCollectionViewData() {

        // Build a parse query object
        var query = PFQuery(className:"Tops")

        // Check to see if there is a search term
        if searchBar.text != "" {
            query.whereKey("uploader", containsString: searchBar.text.lowercaseString)
        }

        // Fetch data from the parse platform
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            // The find succeeded now rocess the found objects into the countries array
            if error == nil {

                // Clear existing country data
                tops.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)

                // Add country objects to our array
                if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                    tops = Array(objects.generate())
                }

                // reload our data into the collection view
                self.collectionView.reloadData()

            } else {
                // Log details of the failure
                println("Error: \(error!) \(error!.userInfo!)")
            }
        }
    }

    /*
    ==========================================================================================
    UICollectionView protocol required methods
    ==========================================================================================
    */

    func numberOfSectionsInCollectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tops.count
    }

    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("mySingleCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SingleRowCell


        // Display the country name
        if let value = tops[indexPath.row]["topsLabel"] as? String {
            cell.topsLabel.text = value
        }

        // Display "initial" flag image
        var initialThumbnail = UIImage(named: "question")
            cell.topsImageView.image = initialThumbnail

        // Fetch final flag image - if it exists
        if let value = tops[indexPath.row]["tops"] as? PFFile {
            let finalImage = tops[indexPath.row]["tops"] as? PFFile
            finalImage!.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let imageData = imageData {
                        cell.topsImageView.image = UIImage(data:imageData)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return cell
    }

    /*
    ==========================================================================================
    Segue methods
    ==========================================================================================
    */

    // Process collectionView cell selection
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let currentObject = tops[indexPath.row]
        performSegueWithIdentifier("CollectionViewToDetailView", sender: currentObject)
    }

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        // If a cell has been selected within the colleciton view - set currentObjact to selected
        var currentObject : PFObject?
        if let country = sender as? PFObject{
            currentObject = sender as? PFObject
        } else {
            // No cell selected in collectionView - must be a new country record being created
            currentObject = PFObject(className:"Tops")
        }

        // Get a handle on the next story board controller and set the currentObject ready for the viewDidLoad method
        var detailScene = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController
        detailScene.currentObject = (currentObject)
    }


    /*
    ==========================================================================================
    Process Search Bar interaction
    ==========================================================================================
    */

    func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Dismiss the keyboard
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Reload of table data
        self.loadCollectionViewData()
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Dismiss the keyboard
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Reload of table data
        self.loadCollectionViewData()
    }

    func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        // Clear any search criteria
        searchBar.text = ""

        // Dismiss the keyboard
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

        // Reload of table data
        self.loadCollectionViewData()
    }

    /*
    ==========================================================================================
    Process memory issues
    To be completed
    ==========================================================================================
    */

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

UPLOADING Image

```
  @IBAction func uploadButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        var imageText = uploadMessage.text

        if uploadPreviewImageView.image == nil {
            //image is not included alert user
            println("Image not uploaded")
        }else {

            var posts = PFObject(className: "Tops")
            posts["imageText"] = imageText
            posts["uploader"] = PFUser.currentUser()
            posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error == nil {

                    var imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.uploadPreviewImageView.image)
                    var parseImageFile = PFFile(name: "uploaded_image.png", data: imageData)
                    posts["imageFile"] = parseImageFile
                    posts.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({
                        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                        if error == nil {

                            println("finished")
                            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goHomeFromUpload", sender: self)

                        }else {

                            println(error)
                        }


                    })


                }else {
                    println(error)

                }
```

Comment: Is topsImageView set as a PFImageview on the storyboard also?

Comment: In storyboard I have set the an UIimage view as an PFImageView class

Comment: I have code that looks exactly the same, do you have anything else that interacts with topsImageView in your class?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question to show all the code in the class. Please feel free to ask me if any piece of code from other  classes swell.

Comment: Can you try with a different thumbnail on Parse? Maybe there's something wrong with this one for some reason? I really can't see anything that's wrong and have been comparing this to my code which does the exact same thing successfully.

Comment: Just a thought also, you can try to loadInBackgroundWithBlock and see if you can manually assign the data you get back into a UIImage and assign it again - just to see if it works.

Comment: I only have tops image view. Can you also have a look at my topsviewcontroller where I retrieve. I may have some errors...

Comment: it looks good - the only thing I would change is the performSegueWithIdentifier - the sender should be self not the object. I don't think that is the issue though because on your Detail controller if the data wasn't there the "if let" would not execute and you would not see the error. Try to load it with a block and print a line in the block to see if it works.

Comment: Thank you. Huge mystery. You can now see how I upload my images. question updated. Do you mean                 `topsImageView.loadInBackgroundWithBlock`? I am know getting an error saying PFIMageView Does not have a member loadinbackgroundwithblock

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84196/discussion-between-thefredelement-and-satsuki).